# Android RecyclerView best practice for displaying items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a reyclerview in which every time I add an item I add it at index 0, Usually when you add an item a given index you can do it like so

```
mAdapter.add(0, item)
mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0)
```

the problem is the item will be added to index 0 but the user will have to scroll to view it, of course, there is a solution which is by simply doing the following

```
messageAdapter.add(0, item)
messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

the problem here is that by calling "notifyDataSetChanged()" the item will appear all of sudden inside the list which I don't like I want to have a nice and smooth animation for when the item is added, another solution is to manually smooth scroll the recyclerView whenever an item is added using our first code, this solution is the best but it has some problems.

when the user is viewing item at index 999 and a new item is added the view will be scrolled to index 0 which can be kind of annoying for the user, the solution is simple for this problem, we can check if the item at index 0 is visible if it is, then scroll to index 0, this is the perfect solution for my problem.

So my question is, is there any other way to implement the functionality that I want to achieve without having to do that work? I would like to know what the simplest way is, thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try using diff util it will be better for performance for updating recyclerview
 https://blog.mindorks.com/the-powerful-tool-diff-util-in-recyclerview-android-tutorial

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using groupie library, which is probably doing most of that work for me. 

https://github.com/lisawray/groupie

Comment: based on the documentation the say "Modifying the contents of the GroupAdapter in any way automatically sends change notifications. Adding an item calls notifyItemAdded(); adding a group calls notifyItemRangeAdded()" so if you used the diff util you will determine what function you can call please check how to use the diff util and it will work fine with it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, my code is working fine and it is applying what I want to achieve, the question says "best practice" I want to know if there is a better way for making sure of when to scroll the view and when not to scroll the view... my problem isn't with the adapter and what or how to add items...